# One-factor-at-a-time dimensionality

Tags: experiment-design

Saltelly et al., in ["How to avoid a perfunctory sensitivity analysis"](http://www.nusap.net/spe/Saltelli_and_Annoni_2010.pdf) to discourage the use of One-factor-at-a-time have an example with a shpere in a cube and it says in section 3.

*"all the points of the OAT design are by construction internal to the sphere."*

And then starts for the case of two variables (k=2) and says that the area of the circle inscribed in the unit square.

I cannot understand why the OAT should be a circle in a case of two variables (or sphere in k=3).

For instance the example from [here](https://doi.org/10.1038/s41598-019-47846-6) doesn't seem like exploring a circle

[image]

[Here](https://youtu.be/_PnVw2WTZm8?t=1218), is a recording talking about it